# my strncmp isnt working for two 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, c, char, matching, strncmp

I am trying to compare and find matches in my two arrays but it is not working can any one help?

```
const char spam[30][30] = {"cash bonus","earn money","fast cash","free access","free gift","free membership",
    "giveaway","million dollars","information you requested","act now","winner","you have been selected",
    "congratulations","lose weight","meet singles","no cost","no interest","social securtiy number","bonus",
    "ad","join millions","opt in","warranty","instant","prize","lowest price","get paid","get out of debt","one time","winning"};
    char resp[SIZE][SIZE];//response string array 
    printf("Enter an email to be checked for spam\n");
    scanf("%s", &resp);
    
    //check if there is a match
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++){
        resp[i][j] = tolower(resp[i][j]);//make it lowercase
        int match = strncmp(resp[i], spam[i] );//compare 
        if(match == 0){
            printf("This email is spam! :(\n");
        }else{
            printf("No match :) \n");
        }//if else
    }//for loop2
    }//for loop1
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &resp)` is ***very*** wrong. The type of `&resp` is `char (*)[SIZE][SIZE]`, not the `char *` that the `%s` format expects. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: what should I use instead of %s?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]. Also you should format your code properly, it is pretty unreadable.

Comment: `strncmp` takes three arguments. Your compiler should complain about that. You probably wanted `strcmp`.

Comment: You should use a loop to read each of the 30 strings one by one.

Comment: You are doing your `if` _inside_ your _inner_ loop--not what you want. Move closing brace to just under the `tolower` line

Comment: @sonya, there is no magic format specifier that reads a text file and splits it into a list of expressions. A good start would be to read the whole file into a buffer (array of `char`), write a function to look for a string in a larger buffer, call this function in a loop for each spam pattern. You should also consider, when having multiple strings, to have an array of pointers to strings rather than a 2d array of `char`. There are better algorithms that manages to look for multiple patterns in one pass without keeping the textfile in memory, but i guess that is overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really accomplish your goal in this way. Your spam library elements consist of 2 words separated by space. But your input is just a single word in each `resp[i]`. (There is no simple way to take input in the 2D array aside from doing it word by word using `scanf()`.
So when you compare a single word `resp[i]` to a double word string `cash bonus`, it will ***always*** return `false`.
[Here](https://courses.linuxchix.org/c-programming-2002/example-writing-spam-filter-c.html) is a guide that can help you. Also, I would love to update the question. Is there any way to identify spam messages with a dictionary of strings, like the `spam` 2D array?

Comment: I am adding it here because its too long for a comment section to the question.